# cmake - preset settings for entries from ini file

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I have a project that uses some third party libraries. So each time I setup this project with CMake, I have to set each entry (path of the third party library) on the GUI of CMake. I improve this by making CMake script guess the path by this script (learn this technique from OGRE):

```
# Guess the paths.
set( OGRE_SOURCE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Ogre" CACHE STRING "Path to OGRE source code (see http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=CMake+Quick+Start+Guide)" )
```

So each time I setup with CMake, it will automatic fill the entry OGRE_SOURCE. But that doesn't enough. If the Ogre source is not in the path

```
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Ogre"
```

, then I have to open and edit the CMake script or I have to edit the entry on the GUI of CMake. I find that pretty inconvenient, especially when you link to a lot of third party libraries.

So I want to use another technique: preset settings for entries from file - CMake reads the presets from file PresetEntries.txt (that I make) and apply the these presets on the entries (It's a lot quicker to edit the path in text file than on the GUI of CMake).

Here my idea about this preset file: PresetEntries.txt

```
OGRE_SOURCE=E:/Source/ogre
```

I found that CMake can [read a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744998/4608491), but if I use this, I have to do string manipulations.

CMake has [the file CMakeCache.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22039411/4608491) to save the settings on the CMake GUI, but I want it to be simple: it should only has the preset settings that need to be pre-set.

So I wonder if CMake support this preset settings for entries from file.

**Edit:**
So I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17597673/4608491) and see that CMake can set config from file, but this require to fire cmake with the -C mysettings.cmake, but I wanna it to be automatically with CMake GUI - just edit the file and hit generate button in CMake GUI. So I wanna make this question more specific:
In my CMakeLists.txt should have script like this:

```
# Guess the paths.
#I wanna have this function from C++
#https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
GetPrivateProfileString("OGRE",         #lpAppName
                        "OGRE_SOURCE",  #lpKeyName
                        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dependencies/Ogre", #lpDefault
                        OGRE_SOURCE_VAR,#lpReturnedString
                        MAX_PATH,       #nSize, may be can reduce this variable
                        "LibPath.ini")  #lpFileName

set( OGRE_SOURCE "${OGRE_SOURCE_VAR}" CACHE STRING "Path to OGRE source code" )
```

In the file LibPath.ini

```
[OGRE]
OGRE_SOURCE = "E:/Source/ogre"
```

So the user can choose to either use the ini file or not.

I don't know if there any way I can use a function that similar to function GetPrivateProfileString (of C++) in CMake.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Why did you lose the settings. Did you remove the build folder?

Comment: Use `-C` option of `cmake`, like described in [that question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597673/cmake-preload-script-for-cache).

Comment: @Th.Thielemann: I didn't lose the settings, the settings just don't right anymore. For example, I move the CMake project to multiple PC, thus the Lib path doesn't stay the same in multiple PC.

Comment: In case all PCs are cloned from one/have the same folder structure you can try the `-C` way.

Comment: sorry :p but I wanna edit the question to make it more clear what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the function to read the ini file, so what I can do is create a simple function that read simple txt file for myself.

1. I declare the function in 1 file for other file use it

"\CMake\Dependencies\CommonFunc.cmake"

```
#------------Define function Read file------------
macro( readSettingFile KEY DEFAULT_RESULT STRING_RESULT_OUT)

    unset(STRING_RESULT)
    # Read the file
    file( READ "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/LibPath.txt" LIB_PATH_STR )

    # Set the variable "Esc" to the ASCII value 27 - basically something
    # which is unlikely to conflict with anything in the file contents.
    string(ASCII 27 Esc)

    # Turn the contents into a list of strings, each ending with an Esc.
    # This allows us to preserve blank lines in the file since CMake
    # automatically prunes empty list items during a foreach loop.
    string(REGEX REPLACE "\n" "${Esc};" LIB_PATH_LINES "${LIB_PATH_STR}")

    foreach(LINE ${LIB_PATH_LINES})
        if("${LINE}" MATCHES "${KEY}")
            #remove the key, leave the content untouch
            string(REPLACE "${KEY}" "" STRING_RESULT ${LINE})
            # Swap the appended Esc character back out in favour of a line feed
            string(REGEX REPLACE "${Esc}" "" STRING_RESULT ${STRING_RESULT})
        endif()
    endforeach()

    if("${STRING_RESULT}" STREQUAL "")
        set( STRING_RESULT ${DEFAULT_RESULT} )
    endif()


    #message( STATIC "---GTA Sa-----" "[${STRING_RESULT}]" )
endmacro()
```

(I need the help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30227627/4608491) to write this function :p)

2. Here is how I use

For example: "\CMake\Dependencies\Ogre.cmake"

```
#include common functions
include( CMake/Dependencies/CommonFunc.cmake )
#---------------Guess the paths.----------------------
#----Set OGRE_SOURCE
readSettingFile(    "OGRE_SOURCE="
                    "E:/Source/ogre"
                    STRING_RESULT
                )
set( OGRE_SOURCE "${STRING_RESULT}" CACHE STRING "Path to OGRE Source" )
#----Set OGRE_BINARIES
readSettingFile(    "OGRE_BINARIES="
                    "E:/Source/_build/ogre"
                    STRING_RESULT
                )
set( OGRE_BINARIES "${STRING_RESULT}" CACHE STRING "Path to OGRE's build folder generated by CMake" )
```

3. Here is the setting file

"\LibPath.txt"

```
OGRE_SOURCE=E:/Source/ogre
OGRE_BINARIES=E:/Source/_build/ogre
```

Answer (score 1):

The external libraries should be included by one of the following commands

```
find_package(ttnlib REQUIRED HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
include_directories(${ttnlib_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} ${TTNLIB_LIBRARY})
```

or

```
find_library(MY_EXTERNAL_LIB name COOLSTUFF libCOOLSTUFF libCOOLSTUF.so hints /usr/local/lib)
```

The search for the external packages and libraries should only be necessary for the first run of cmake.

Comment: Agreed, this is the canonical way to support external dependencies in CMake. Though, I find the OP's solution generally interesting, as I'm looking at writing some file parsing code in cmake myself